# wordpress permission issue while creating pages oder copying pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a strange issue on my wordpress page. can't create any pages. I can only send them to review. ... My user has admin rights.

Same issue while trying to copy a page. No further errors are displayed.

any ideas for me?

Comment: Are you using the latest WordPress? 0. Try updating WordPress. 1. try with deactivating all plugin,  any plugin may causing the issue, 2. Try activating classic editor plugin, 3. Try switching to default theme.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution.

the hoster must have had a database crash. The Wordpress database was corrupt.

In all tables there was no primary key and no indexes left.

A manual intervention was necessary. After I gave all tables a primary key again the problem was solved.

**Solution**

1. Backup of the database
2. Export of the database as SQL file
3. Manual repair of the tables

   - Create Table had to be adapted (primary key + index were missing)
   - do not forget to check for values that were in ID field 0, e.g. in the audit logs there were numerous entries with id 0. these must also be removed.
4. Delete the current database
5. Import of the corrected sql file